# Given the word SCHOOL, how many different 3 letter arrangements can you form?

Tags: combinatorics

I found this question in an assessment book and noticed the answer key was wrong (via manual listing and an alternative method) but could not figure out why (the answer key's method seems reasonable).

1. Can you help me understand why the answer key's method undercounts?
2. Can you help me fix the working in the answer key (but use the same approach)?

Please comment for question 1 even if you can't solve question 2!

Working and comparison of methods:

[image]

Comment: The division by $2!$ would have been done in order to "forget" which O was which since there are two of them in order to not differentiate between words like O**O**L and **O**OL.  However, such a distinction doesn't matter when there is only one or no O's used in the word.

Comment: Hi, please add some thought you have put into this/attempts you have made. Also try to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions, since it is searchable and pictures are not. As a hint to why it is wrong: $^6P_3$ counts the permutations that contain 2 times the letter 'O' twice. To compensate for that, they divide by 2, but that not all strings of 3 letters contain 'O' twice so you divide 'too many possibilities' by 2. A solution could be to look at strings that contain one or zero times the ...

Comment: ...letter 'O' and look at the cases that contain both 'O' 's seperately.

Comment: "*Can I fix method 2*"  I wouldn't bother trying to shoehorn it in... its not worth the effort.  That said, method1 isn't as efficient as it should be either.  You can break into *two* cases rather than three.  Either both O's are used, giving $4\times 3=12$ outcomes (*choose the other letter used other than O, and which position it occupies in the word*), or at most one O is used, giving $5P3=5\times 4\times 3=60$ outcomes (*using your notation*) for a total of $12+60=72$

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I came up with method 1, which I write in full form for clarity over efficiency (includes 1 more term). I find method 2 very attractive as it has only 1 term and presently suppose you are right and it cannot be made to work. Please let me know if you have an ingenious method of making method 2 work!

Answer (score 0):

$60 = \frac {5!}{2!}$ counts all of the three-letter combinations of the elements $\{S,C,H,O,L\}$ -- the distinct letters of SCHOOL.

It does not count strings with 2 O's

There are $12$ three-letter strings with two O's.  (4 for the choice of the 3rd letter times 3 for its placement in the string.)

Comment: In your first line, it would be better to say all the $3$-combinations of the letters of SCHOL or all the three-letter strings that can be formed using distinct letters of SCHOL.